# How to print point into the right position into the canvas? Made with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, canvas

How to bring the Point at to the right place into the canvas?

```
let canvas = []
let canvasHeight  = process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1] -25
let canvasWidth = process.stdout.getWindowSize()[0]
function createCanvas (){
        for(i = 0; canvasHeight > i; i++){
                const row = []
                for(j = 0; canvasWidth > j; j++){

                row.push(" ")

                }
                canvas.push(row)
        }




}
createCanvas()


function createAPointIntoTheCanvas (x,y) {
if(x>= 0 &&x < canvasWidth && y >= 0 && y < canvasHeight){
        canvas[x][y] = "+"
}

}
createAPointIntoTheCanvas(5,5)


console.log(canvas.join(" "))
```

The problem is that the point is written to the canvas but into the wrong place. Written with NodeJs

PS: Please copy the sourcecode into a js file. Afterwards start the file with node nameOfYourFile.js.

Comment: Do you really use NodeJS?

Comment: copy this sourcecode into a js file and save it start with node yourNameOfTheFile.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be this line:

```
let canvasHeight  = process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1] -25
```

It results in a height of 0 if the window is small.
If I set the width and height manually your code works.

```
let canvas = []
let canvasHeight  = 5  //process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1] -25
let canvasWidth = 5    //process.stdout.getWindowSize()[0]

//...

createCanvas()
createAPointIntoTheCanvas(2,2)
console.log(canvas)
```

Result: the `+` is at `2,2`

```
[
  [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
]
```